# Build automation on changing classes

Tags: automation, css-selectors, ui-automation, browser-automation

I'm using [Automa](https://www.automa.site/) browser extension to automate a tedious task and I'm trying to solve an issue. I want to automate a click on a CSS selector with this format:
.ad-format-card:nth-child(1) ._ngcontent-iqt-10:nth-child(2)

The problem is that the name changes every time the page is loaded :( For example ngcontent-igt becomes ngcontent-fej etc.

Any idea on how to solve this issue by mapping the CSS selector to something that is fix?

I tried with Xpath but I have the same problem.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided (the class contains `_ngcontent-`), you could use the following css selector to match on that class:

```py
'[class*="_ngcontent-"]'
```

It uses `*=`, which means that the `_ngcontent-` could appear anywhere in the class field to match. Swap `._ngcontent-iqt-10` from your question with `[class*="_ngcontent-"]` and see if that matches better. (There's probably a better selector to use, but this is based on the details available in your question.)